# Passing generic Class as argument to function in swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Below is my method in which there is fetch I make on a Managed object Class Appointment. I need to use same function for other similar managed object Classes. How do I pass different "Class" as parameter every time as I need. And also use it to fetch as I have currently "Appointment" Class. I might need to use Generics may be. Dont know how though.

```
func getAppointmentArray(aPredicate : String , aModel : Any) -> [Any]
{
    var apptArr = [Any]()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Appointment>(entityName: "Appointment")
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: aPredicate)
    do{
        let records = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

        if let records = records as? [NSManagedObject]{
            if !records.isEmpty{

                print("coreData apptmnt result : \(records)")
                var appointment : Appointment?

                for obj in records
                {

                }
            }else{
                print("No records found")
                apptArr = []
            }
        }
    }catch{
        print("Error")
         apptArr = []
    }
   return apptArr
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The good folks at [Objc.io](https://www.objc.io/) provide a really good approach for this. First declare a protocol which inherits '**NSFetchRequestResult**'  protocol as below.

```
protocol Managed: class, NSFetchRequestResult {
    static var entityName: String { get }
}
```

Now we can provide a very convenient **protocol extension** for our **protocol** '**Managed**'.
We do the check '**Self: NSManagedObject**' as we want the **static method entity()** of the NSManagedObject class to get the '**NSEntityDescription**' describing the entity associated with our class. *Particularly this way we get the entity name dynamically(and conveniently too) for all our ManagedObjects that conform to our protocol.*

```
extension Managed where Self: NSManagedObject {
    static var entityName: String { return entity().name! }
}
```

We now improve the protocol extension by providing a method which conveniently creates a fetch request and then calls a configuration block which might be used to configure the created fetch request by whoever calls it. At the end of this method we do a fetch using the created request.

```
extension Managed where Self: NSManagedObject {
        static var entityName: String { return entity().name! }

        //Continued
        static func fetch(in context: NSManagedObjectContext, configurationBlock: (NSFetchRequest<Self>) -> ()) -> [Self] {
            let request = NSFetchRequest<Self>(entityName: Self.entityName)
            configurationBlock(request)
            return try! context.fetch(request)
        }
}
```

As you can see we do the following things here:

- We make good use of protocols and protocol extensions for making our life easy.
- We get the entity name without needing to write a method for each concrete managed object class that we might create. This is reusable for every managed object class that will conform to 'Managed'
- The fetch method that we wrote makes use of the dynamic and convenient **entityName**.
- The fetch method again makes use of **Self** which is implementation independent here. This way we make FetchRequests which are generic in itself.
- We provide a convenient way to configure the request to whoever calls this method.
- And at atlast we return result after fetching which is also dynamic **[Self]**

To see our protocol in action we can do this for your case:

```
class Appointment: NSManagedObject, Managed{
    //properties for attributes
    //etc...
    //Will I get free implementation for entity name and a fetch method
    //without writing extra code ?
    //Yes why not
}
```

Testing our hard earned knowledge:

```
let aPredicate = "......
let context: NSManagedObjectContext.....
let appointments = Appointment.fetch(in: context) { fetchRequest in
    //Configuration code like adding predicates and sort descriptors
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: aPredicate)
}
```

You can use the same pattern for any other ManagedObjects if they conform to the protocol. Eg a Doctor ManagedObject subclass conforming to our **Managed** protocol:

```
let aPredicate = "......
let context: NSManagedObjectContext.....
let doctors = Doctor.fetch(in: context) { fetchRequest in
    //Configuration code like adding predicates and sort descriptors
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: aPredicate)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for the generic you can do something like this:

```
class FetchingDataHandler<T>{
func getAppointmentArray<T>(forClass : T, aPredicate : String , aModel : Any) -> [Any]
  {
  }
}
```