# Generic FetchRequest

Tags: swift, generics, nsmanagedobject

I have a static function that extends `NSManagedObject` to get an object like so...

`NSManagedObject.get(type: MYUser.self, with: ("id", "SomeUserId"), in: context)`

```
extension NSManagedObject {

    static func get<M: NSManagedObject>(type: M.Type, with kvp: (String, CVarArg), in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> M? {

     guard let name = entity().name else { return nil }
     guard M.entity().propertiesByName[kvp.0] != nil else { Assert("\(name) does not have \(kvp.0)"); return nil }

     let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<M>(entityName: name)
     fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(kvp.0) == %@", kvp.1)

     do {
            let object = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            if let foundObject = object.first { return foundObject }
            return nil
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

The syntax I would like is

`MYUser.get(with: ("id", "SomeUserId"), in: context)`

and to infer the Type from the class that made the call... but I'm unsure what to put in place of the generic here

`NSFetchRequest<M>(entityName: name)`

`NSFetchRequest<???>(entityName: name)`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does putting `M` as the generic type not work for you?

Comment: I want to remove the generic type

Comment: It'll be nil right?

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood your question. Thinking about an answer now...

Comment: I assume you don't want to do something like `let user: MYUser? = MYUser.get(...)`?

Comment: I might want to do that yeah

Comment: It's mainly about cleaner syntax

Comment: This should be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174234/passing-generic-class-as-argument-to-function-in-swift/51197659#51197659.

Comment: Ah yeah that's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link [Passing generic Class as argument to function in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174234/passing-generic-class-as-argument-to-function-in-swift/51197659#51197659) suggested by [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r)

```
protocol Managed where Self: NSManagedObject { }

extension Managed where Self: NSManagedObject {

static func get(with kvp: (String, CVarArg), in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self? {

    guard let name = entity().name else { return nil }
    guard entity().propertiesByName[kvp.0] != nil else { Assert("\(name) does not have \(kvp.0)"); return nil }

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Self>(entityName: name)
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(kvp.0) == %@", kvp.1)

    do {
        let object = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        if let foundObject = object.first { return foundObject }
        return nil
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful if you *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of dumping code only. – You might also want to add a reference to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174234/passing-generic-class-as-argument-to-function-in-swift/51197659#51197659 to your answer, as you were obviously inspired by that solution.

Comment: Sure thing... I thought it was clear from the comments, but you're right I should cite you and the answer you pointed me to..

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind writing `MYUser` twice, you can remove the `type` parameter and specify the type so that Swift can infer `M`:

```
extension NSManagedObject {

    static func get<M: NSManagedObject>(with kvp: (String, CVarArg), in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> M? {

        guard let name = entity().name else { return nil }
        guard M.entity().propertiesByName[kvp.0] != nil else {
            print("\(name) does not have \(kvp.0)")
            return nil
        }

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<M>(entityName: name)
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(kvp.0) == %@", kvp.1)

        do {
            let object = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            if let foundObject = object.first { return foundObject }
            return nil
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

// usage:
let user: MYUser? = MYUser.get(with: ("id", "SomeUserId"), in: context)
```

If you don't want to write `MYUser` twice, then I can't think of any solutions. If `NSManagedObject` were a protocol, you could have used `Self` in there.

Comment: Just to be clear `let user = MYUser.get(with: ("id", "SomeUserId"), in: context)` won't work?

Comment: @Magoo `user`’s type either can’t be inferred, or is just `NSManagedObject`. Try it yourself.

Comment: @Magoo actually the solution shown in Martin R’s link is pretty good as well. Try adapting it.