# How to use generics to return all objects for specific type of NSManagedObject?

Tags: ios, swift, magicalrecord

This is what I need to achieve:

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    class func all<T: Self>(in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [T] { //error: Expected a class type or protocol-constrained type restricting '
        return mr_findAll(in: context) as! [T]
    }
}
```

And I would like to use it like this:

```
let persons = Person.all(in: context)
let hotels = Hotel.all(in: context)
```

Is it possible at all?

`Person` and `Hotel` inherits from `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51197659/1187415.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a fetch request is already generic this can be accomplished only with a protocol extension and associated type, an `NSManagedObject` extension doesn't work without any type cast or annotation.

```
protocol Managed
{
    associatedtype ManagedType: NSManagedObject = Self
    static var entityName : String { get }
    static func all(in context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> [ManagedType]
}

extension Managed where Self : NSManagedObject {
    static var entityName : String { return String(describing:self) }

    static func all(in context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> [ManagedType] {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<ManagedType>(entityName: entityName)
        return try context.fetch(request)
    }
}
```

Just add conformance to `Managed` to all your `NSManagedObject` subclasses then you can use

```
let persons = Person.all(in: context)
let hotels = Hotel.all(in: context)
```

Comment: Ok, how do I conform Person to `Managed`?;)

Comment: In the declaration line:  `class Person: NSManagedObject, Managed { ...`

Comment: You are Genius;) I would buy you a wine for that;) Amazing thing... works as I need;)

Comment: Sorry, I reverted the edit because there are a few bad habits I don't agree with (force unwrapping, *snake_cased* variable names and unnecessary type cast).

Comment: Ok, no problem... I completely agree with you. But it was from third party library (MagicalRecord), and the question was tagged with that... ;) Force unwrapping is also bad... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Honestly the native protocol based Swift solution is much more efficient than the Objective-C library. You can easily extend the protocol to create, delete, sort, filter records without adding any code to the `NSManagedObject` subclasses. I'm using such an extended version in many projects